# Java test setup with NetBeans, Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, build

How could I set up NetBeans and Maven so that:

1. I can easily run my tests from NetBeans (see below)
2. Use the NetBeans debugger on tests that fail
3. I can avoid having to copy lots of boilerplate declarations across all (NetBeans) test projects, of which I have many?

For these tests, I have separate NetBeans projects that collect all the code necessary to run the tests. Because they are larger than usual "unit" tests, they don't use junit or such that NetBeans understands. To run the tests outside NetBeans, I basically run:

```
java -jar mytestframework.jar some other args TestClass1
```

where `mytestframework.jar` is the same JAR for all test projects (defined in some separate project), and `TestClass1` is the main class defining the tests in that particular project.

If I declare `TestClass1` to be the "main class" in NetBeans, it meets all the requirements except that NetBeans will obviously run the main method in `TestClass1`, and not in `mytestframework.jar`. I cannot pick `mytestframework.jar` interactively in NetBeans, but I can open `nbactions.xml` and manually set the run and debug invocations to what they need to be. That's a lot of work, and hard to maintain, given that I have many such test projects.

Is there a better way? Some kind of custom NetBeans action invoking some kind of Maven plugin inherited from a shared parent pom, perhaps, or such?

Comment: You use Maven, so _use_ Maven. Install your testing library as a Maven dependency - add it to your other projects. Then **use jUnit**, don't build a new wheel when the **entire Java community** has decided that the jUnit wheel is perfectly round - if jUnit doesn't do what you want; then that has to do with _what you want_ **not** jUnit.

Comment: Perhaps jUnit is indeed perfectly round, but perhaps what I need is more squared. Instead of debating this, I'd rather have input on my actual question.

Comment: Without detail on why you want what you want, we have an XY problem. No real point in answering how to build a square wheel, because no-one needs a square wheel. For example why can't you include the test library as a dependency and simply invoke the `main` method from a jUnit test in the worst case?

Comment: I can make it work, that is not the question. The question is what is the best way of making it work, given the requirements including #3 -- avoiding lots of boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Options -> Java -> Maven -> Edit Global Custom Goal Definitions...

Here you can create actions available to all projects, eg. execute a jar using the exec:exec goal.

Comment: Ah! Global definitions: I didn't know about those.